# How are core ids determined?

Tags: linux, cpu

Looking at several machines with a Gold 6146 CPU, I found that they all have different (sets of) core IDs, e.g.

```
grep core.id /proc/cpuinfo

core id         : 0
core id         : 0
core id         : 4
core id         : 4
core id         : 1
core id         : 1
core id         : 3
core id         : 3
core id         : 2
core id         : 2
core id         : 10
core id         : 10
core id         : 9
core id         : 9
core id         : 19
core id         : 19
....
```

This one has each core ID appearing twice because of hyperthreading. It is somewhat surprising to see a non-monotonous sequence of core IDs, and even left-out values: the 6146 is a 12-core CPU, but the highest ID here is >12.

On another machine, it gets weirder still:

```
core id         : 0
core id         : 0
core id         : 4
core id         : 4
core id         : 1
core id         : 1
core id         : 3
core id         : 3
core id         : 2
core id         : 2
core id         : 11
core id         : 10
core id         : 8
core id         : 9
core id         : 10
core id         : 19
```

Here, core IDs do not occur in pairs anymore, and the total number of unique IDs is larger than the number of physical cores (16 vs 12).

Comment: I’m not convinced the linked answer gives enough detail, I can re-open this question if it doesn’t.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer! It does not explain where APIC IDs come from, though...

Comment: They come from the firmware AFAICT (and I don’t know what the reasoning is supposed to be there).